# How do I make python show only dividable numbers

Tags: python

So, I am curently trying to write a programm that, when I input a number, it outputs all the numbers in the first numbers range, that can be divided by 3.
The code looks like this, but it is only outputing 0 for me, and I have looked trough simillar situations to no awail.

```
n = ""
print('Ievadi skaitli')
n = int( input( '==> ' ) )
i = 0 
print("Izvada skaitļus kas dalās ar 3" )
while i <= n:
 if i%3==0:
  print(i, end = " "  )
  i += 1
```

Maby someone can point me in the right dirrection and tell me, what am I missing

Comment: Your `i += 1` should not be in the `if` block.

Comment: Any reason not counting by `3` in your loop and get rid of the `if` statement? Before coding, it is a good idea to think about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `i` increased inside the if block. In python you should pay attention to the indention.

This should work for you:

```
print('Ievadi skaitli')
n = int( input( '==> ' ) )
i = 0 
print("Izvada skaitļus kas dalās ar 3" )
while i <= n:
    if i%3==0:
        print(i, end = " "  )
    i += 1
```

More Pythonic way to achieve this is by using `for`:

```
for i in range(0, int( input( '==> ' ) )):
    if i%3 == 0:
        print(i, end=" ")
```

Comment: Thank you. I am really new to the whole python sceene, and the indentation still gives me a lot of troubble, and yeah I found the for in sollution how ever, I wanted to make it work with when.

Comment: `range(0, int( input( '==> ' ) ), 3)` and remove the `if` statement. That whole question does not make much sense.